# What stats test to use on difference of data with fixed effect of time

Tags: r, regression, statistical-significance, biostatistics, differences

I have some data I would like to test statistically and dont know how or where to start. My data consist of 32 of the same genotype tested on Condition A or Condition B, so each condition has 16 of the same genotype. I tested each Condition at the same time for four days and measured each genotype. Also through the experiment some genotypes where lost and have NA data. I then substract the mean difference of Condition A from the mean difference of Condition B. I want to statistically test this difference through time. I am interest if this difference is sign. from Zero essential. What test would work best and how would I model this in R? Below is some made up data of each exposure and condition and the mean for each geno.

```
Data;

Geno    Condition   Volume  Exposure
1   A   9   2
1   A   3   2
1   A   23  2
1   A   3   2
1   A   10  2
1   A   6   2
1   A   8   2
1   A   13  2
1   A   9   2
1   A   7   2
1   A   6   2
1   A   5   2
1   A   5   2
1   A   6   2
1   A   5   2
1   A   20  2
1   A   6.3 3
1   A   19.3    3
1   A   23.3    3
1   A   23.3    3
1   A   17.3    3
1   A   10.3    3
1   A   18.3    3
1   A   14.3    3
1   A   8.3 3
1   A   6.3 3
1   A   21.3    3
1   A   13.3    3
1   A   9.3 3
1   A   29.3    3
1   A   7.3 3
1   A   7.3 3
1   A   29.5    4
1   A   13.5    4
1   A   36.5    4
1   A   15.5    4
1   A   35.5    4
1   A   25.5    4
1   A   27.5    4
1   A   27.5    4
1   A   37.5    4
1   A   29.5    4
1   A   53.5    4
1   A   13.5    4
1   A   33.5    4
1   A   18.5    4
1   A   15.5    4
1   A   31.5    4
1   B   30.5    2
1   B   14.5    2
1   B   12.5    2
1   B   9.5 2
1   B   20.5    2
1   B   11.5    2
1   B   5.5 2
1   B   6.5 2
1   B   9.5 2
1   B   8.5 2
1   B   2.5 2
1   B   9.5 2
1   B   12.5    2
1   B   7.5 2
1   B   18.5    2
1   B   10.5    2
1   B   9.9 3
1   B   NA  3
1   B   19.9    3
1   B   3.9 3
1   B   10.9    3
1   B   6.9 3
1   B   7.9 3
1   B   5.9 3
1   B   3.9 3
1   B   4.9 3
1   B   4.9 3
1   B   7.9 3
1   B   19.9    3
1   B   12.9    3
1   B   7.9 3
1   B   3.9 3
1   B   13.6    4
1   B   NA  4
1   B   13.6    4
1   B   8.6 4
1   B   8.6 4
1   B   8.6 4
1   B   10.6    4
1   B   13.6    4
1   B   7.6 4
1   B   13.6    4
1   B   7.6 4
1   B   2.6 4
1   B   18.6    4
1   B   8.6 4
1   B   13.6    4
1   B   11.6    4

Mean;

Cond  Exp_1   Exp_2   Exp_3
A 8.625 14.675  44.25
B 11.875    8.766666667 29.13333333
```